# Empty Dictionary sent over socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, dictionary

i currently have the code to send data over a socket and it is working except the dictionary i am sending over has nothing in it. Am i doing something wrong within this code?

```
class ChessBoard(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, rows=8, columns=8, size=70, color1="White", color2="lightgrey"):

        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        self.size = size
        self.color1 = color1
        self.color2 = color2
        self.pieces = {}
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,
                            width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height, background="bisque")
        self.canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=2, pady=2)
        color = self.color2

        for row in range(self.rows):
               color = self.color1 if color == self.color2 else self.color2
               for col in range(self.columns):
                  x1 = (col * self.size)
                  y1 = (row * self.size)
                  x2 = x1 + self.size
                  y2 = y1 + self.size
                  self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, outline="black", fill=color, tags="square")
                  color = self.color1 if color == self.color2 else self.color2


def addpiece(self):

        self.canvas.WhiteKing = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'E:\\Final Project + Report\\Pieces\\WhiteKing.png')
        self.canvas.create_image(0,0, image=self.canvas.WhiteKing, tags="WhiteKing", anchor="c")
        self.placepiece("WhiteKing", row = 7, column = 4)

        self.canvas.WhiteQueen = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'E:\\Final Project + Report\\Pieces\\WhiteQueen.png')
        self.canvas.create_image(0,0, image=self.canvas.WhiteQueen, tags="WhiteQueen", anchor="c")
        self.placepiece("WhiteQueen", row = 7, column = 3) ######


def placepiece(self, name, row, column):
        self.pieces[name] = (row, column)
        x0 = (column * self.size) + int(self.size/2)
        y0 = (row * self.size) + int(self.size/2)
        self.canvas.coords(name, x0, y0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()                                                                     
    board = ChessBoard(root)
    board.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="true", padx=4, pady=4)
    board.addpiece()
    root.mainloop()
```

Here is my code:

```
        serverName = '127.0.0.1'
        serverPort = 8000
        root = tk.Tk()
        a = Final_Chess_Game.ChessBoard(root)
        serializedDict = json.dumps(a.pieces)
        self.sock.sendto(serializedDict.encode(),(serverName,serverPort))
        print(serializedDict)
```

so im importing a dictionary from another file which contains all the pieces when the program is ran.

Here is the picture of what im receiving:

[sent data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhW7P.png)

[received data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNhxR.png)

Comment: Is your code a part of class? What is the `Final_Chess_Game.Chessboard` method?

Comment: yes ChessBoard is a class, the class contains the dictionary i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you might not like this answer, but it's receiving an empty dictionary because you're *sending* an empty dictionary!  The code functions as expected, the problem is that `a.pieces` is empty or is a data structure that serializes to an empty dictionary.  If you post more code maybe we can help diagnose further.  As it stands it's a bit difficult to tell.

Just for fun, try this.

```
serverName = '127.0.0.1'
serverPort = 8000
root = tk.Tk()
a = Final_Chess_Game.ChessBoard(root)
a.addpiece()
serializedDict = json.dumps(a.pieces)
self.sock.sendto(serializedDict.encode(),(serverName,serverPort))
print(serializedDict)
```

Comment: i actually just tested the code on a test dictionary and it works! so yes the problem is with my dictionary. the only time my dictionary is filled up with data is when i run the program and i think that is the problem i am having, i will nevertheless  update the answer with the rest of the code!

Comment: okay, and how do you create `Final_Chess_Game`?  It looks like you need to run the `.addpiece` method in order to populate the dictionary.  Unless `Final_Chess_Game` is doing that, `.pieces` will never be populated!

Comment: Final_Chess_Game is only the name of the file. i found out that only way my dictionary gets filled with data is when i actually run my program.

Comment: So is there no other way to fix this problem?

Comment: I thought you said it was working, sorry!  Is it not working still?

Comment: no its still not working, i am still getting an empty dictionary.. :(

Comment: the trick here is that your socket is working fine but your program is not

Comment: my program runs fine but the problem is that the dictionary is only filled up once its ran, is there any way i can notify the socket when the program has started to it can retireve the info?

Comment: Perhaps, but you need to include the code that you're using to run your program in order for us to help with that!

Comment: sure, sorry about that!